# WWI : odds to cross the man's land alive

Tags: world-war-one

During the first world war, what where the odds to cross the no man's land alive ?

Not to mention staying alive once in the enemy's trench, just the odds to still be alive to either retreat or reach the other side's trench ?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess that depends on how many coils of barbed wire you have to cross on the way over. Also, are you making the journey alone or will there be a lot of other idiots running alongside you?

Comment: Both sides frequently sent patrols out into the area between assaults as well.

Comment: Consider it's an actual assault, so count a lot of other idiots. For the number of barbed wire, I have no idea.

Comment: even then, it'd be a very broad selection of possible scenarios. Geography, weather, effectiveness of the preparatory bombardment, time of day, stage of the campaign/battle, etc. etc.

Answer (score 3):

First, I will assume that OP refers to the case of *going over the top* on an assault rather than engaging in a surreptitious raid across no-man's land.

Consider the assault on [Vimy Ridge](http://www.warmuseum.ca/cwm/exhibitions/vimy/index_e.shtml) by the Canadian Corps over Easter Weekend, 1917. 
 The assault was performed over 4 days by 15,000 men of the Canadian Corps, of whom nearly 3600 would die and over 7,000 more would be wounded. This gave a survival rate of about 76%, and a not-wounded rate of about 29%.

The odds during the earlier French and British assault on Vimy were worse.

Similarly, it is widely held that the survival rate of junior officers, those fools standing tall and exhorting the men to greater effort, was substantially worse than average.

**Update**:

It is argued below that my phrasing *those fools* above is inappropriate, as those individuals were *merely* brave. I disagree, and offer as evidence the definition of **Foolhardy**: *recklessly bold or rash*.

Any competent Allied commander in WWI should have known that the success of Britain and France during the Napoleonic Wars a century earlier had resulted from, respectively, steadfast *defence* under cover of a reverse slope, and bold *skirmishing* from covered terrain. The massed attacks engaged in from 1914 to 1918 by France and Britain bore no resemblance what-so-ever to successful Napoleonic tactics and would have had the same lack of success a century earlier as they actually demonstrated.

Comment: I think the word *fools* is offensive in this context. Perhaps *brave men* could be substituted?

Comment: @andy256: I disagree, and highly recommend *Infantry Attacks* by Erwin Rommel to your consideration. At a time and place when Allied junior officers measured their life expectancy in minutes, Rommel over 2 years repeatedly led German units that over-achieved their objective and had to retreat from lack of support. He was seconded to the German staff as one of the officers who trained the first German *infiltration troops* that broke the Russian Front open in 1917 and almost did likewise in France in early 1918. Yes, those officers were brave; but they were also blatant fools.

Comment: Even with these stats, it can't be known what fraction of the number at Vimy fell before reaching the enemy trench, or in one of the counterattacks that often happened, or when trying to extend the advance past the first trench, or by the shelling that took place during all of this period.

Comment: Kinda with Pieter on the "fools" issue. From a strict personal survival standpoint, such behavior is foolish. More to the point, I've seen authors describing tactics of the era use similar verbiage. I haven't looked into it deeply, but from fictionalized works I get the impression that kind of fatalistic sense of humor about the situation was typical for the era.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens they acted foolishly, but not because they were fools. They acted as they had been drilled to act, acting any different would have gotten them killed as well, just by a firing squad after a quick court martial. The training regimen for British (and American) troops was so rigid and foolish that many things that are just common sense were subject to get you reprimanded or worse. Things like ducking under fire, firing from cover, etc. etc. were considered "ungentlemanly" and not allowed... Call the authors of those training manuals fools, not the people who acted on that training

Comment: @jwenting: Yet, the Canadian success at Vimy was precisely because they did all those things and more, with the full support and encouragement of Currie. Likewise for other Commonwealth troops when they were provided with their own officers, as well as the US troops. Those *authors* were morons, not fools, at any time after the 1914 summer campaign had concluded.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens they were fools in believing that 18th century chivalry has a place in WW1 trench warfare. They seemed to come around after a few million people died following their instructions and started writing more modern combat manuals...